# Run IIS Manager in 32-bit mode

Tags: iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

I want to define some configuration values at the root level of IIS. (Connection string and some configuration values across some ASP.NET sites.)

I went into IIS Manager and set them in the default web site. I had some issues and eventually discovered that it worked fine for apps running in 64-bit mode but not for apps in 32-bit mode. (We have some legacy 3rd party DLLs that only work in 32-bit mode, so some of our sites will have to run in 32-bit mode.)

I got it working by manually editing the root web.config in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config so that it had the same settings as the one IIS Manager updated in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config.

Is there a way either to force IIS Manager to update both or run IIS Manager to run in 32-bit mode so we can update it through the interface, even if we have to do it twice? (It just seems safer than manually editing the root web.config file.)

Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible. As IIS itself is mostly 64 bit, if you force IIS Manager to run as 32 bit, it can easily break.

Comment: So,  basically, I will need to manually edit the 32-bit web.config file if I want to do this?

Comment: IIS management is usually script based, so you should write some PowerShell scripts. Manually editing the files would be too slow.